# Mist coat for plaster patched extensively with joint compound?

Tags: painting, plaster

We recently had to strip all paint (down to original plaster) from the main hall of our 1920s home after discovering that the paint was peeling off very easily. Since we had the opportunity I went ahead and patched every small divot/scratch in the plaster (lots since this was a hallway/stairwell) along with several small cracks with quick-set mud. The surface is probably 2/3 plaster and 1/3 mud. Would you recommend a mist coat, or some sort of primer for this application? I'm concerned about a mist coat adhering to the mud in the patched areas, but I've read not to prime plaster.

Comment: I'm not totally sure of this but there is something called a "bonding agent", which is kinda like a primer but intended to give some "teeth" between the plaster and the paint.  This is NOT an answer, just a comment, hopefully others here smarter than me will chime in,

Comment: Since you didn't patch with plaster, this answer sheds some light on priming old plaster (and drywall compound) https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/41640/18078